# new form doesn't allow to go back to the main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm opening a new form like this:

```
Form formulario = new Editar_POIs());
formulario.ShowDialog();
```

Now, when the new form opens and I want to go back to the Main form (with the new form opened), I can't... Either if I click in the main form or if I try to switch using Alt + Tab it won't go back to the main form. I then need to close the opened form to be able to use the Main form again.

Any ideas how to avoid this? I want the user to be able to have the 2nd form opened while he does some operations in the main form, then go back to the 2nd form and enter some values the Main form displays.

Comment: It usually helps if you include a language tag, so that it's clear what you're asking. It also helps to get the question to the people who can answer it more quickly (which gets you answers faster). Can you [edit] to add a tag for that? Thanks.

Comment: It usually helps if you look at the doc before too. ShowDialog behavior is clearly explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
formulario.Show();
```

ShowDialog() does not let you go back and use the main form until the 'child' form is closed.